# Bitbucket POST-Receive Webhooks are not triggering Jenkins builds if configured with HTTPS

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

Recently we have configured trusted SSL certs for our Jenkins, and it is running fine on both HTTP & HTTPS.

Bitbucket Post-Receive WebHooks build were running fine until HTTPS configuration.

After configuring https, Jenkins auto build triggering is not happening even after changing the post-receive webhooks url to HTTPS as follows. Please note we have empty POLL SCM enabled inside Jenkins job.

https://jenkins.mycompany.com/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@stash.mycompany.local:7999/repo/mybranch.git

Please note my observations

1. Inside Jenkins job, Git-Polling log is able to find the commit changes but not triggering the jobs.
2. Builds are getting triggered when we hit https://jenkins.mycompany.com/git/notifyCommit?url=ssh://git@stash.mycompany.local:7999/repo/mybranch.git from browser.
3. Under Jenkins Master logs, found that the branch indexing is happening but not triggering the job.

   ```
     ex:  #20190423.054300 branch indexing action completed: FAILURE in 47 ms
   ```
4. Lastly, Build are running fine when we use HTTP url in post-receive webhook.

   Can someone explain me what could be the problem.